# Python recursion in appending lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want to append to a list recursively but I cannot come up with a function that works. The function takes two arguments `times` and `data`. `times` should be the number of times to append the data.

Here is my code so far:

```
def replicate_recur(times, data):
    result2 = []
    if times == 0:
        result2.append(data)
    else:
        result2.append(data)
        replicate_recur(times - 1, data)
    return result2
```

Comment: result2 is local here so you have to mention result2.extend(replicate_recur(times - 1, data))

Comment: you can simply achieve this by using  result.extend(data*times)

Comment: i got instructions to use recursion

Comment: @MosesKoledoye 's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your code work, you need to `extend` the list in the current execution with the output of the next recursive call. Also, the lowest depth of the recursion should be defined by `times = 1`:

```
def replicate_recur(times, data):
    result2 = []
    if times == 1:
        result2.append(data)
    else:
        result2.append(data)
        result2.extend(replicate_recur(times - 1, data))
    return result2
```

On another note, you can simply replicate your list with:

```
def replicate(times, data):
    return [data]*times
```

Comment: Nice one worked out perfectly. So the problem with my code was that every time the function recurred my list was empty?

Comment: Not really, you were calling `replicate_recur` but not doing anything with the returned result. If this is for a real use case and not for learning how recursive functions work, please use the other offered method.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a intermediate list to append to in each recursive call. That avoids these redefinition problems you're encountering currently:

```
def replicate_recur(times, data, result=None):
    if result is None:  # create a new result if no intermediate was given
        result = []
    if times == 1:
        result.append(data)
    else:
        result.append(data)
        replicate_recur(times - 1, data, result)  # also pass in the "result"
    return result
```

When called:

```
>>> replicate_recur(4, 2)
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xrange` for this, there is no point to use recursion unless it is a coding test.

```
def replicate(times, data):
    result2 = []
    for i in xrange(times):
        result2.append(data)
    return result2
```

Same function can be written in a recursive way like this:

```
def replicate_recur(times, data, listTest=None):
    # If a list has not been passed as argument create an empty one
    if(listTest == None):
        listTest = []
    # Return the list if we need to replicate 0 more times
    if times == 0:
        return listTest
    # If we reach here at least we have to replicate once
    listTest.append(data)
    # Recursive call to replicate more times, if needed and return the result
    replicate_recur(times-1, data, listTest)
    return listTest
```

Comment: i got one that works was trying out if i can do the same with recursion. Theres a perfect answer below

Comment: I have updated my answer, Have a look at it and accept it if you think this is what you needed

Comment: Suggested some edits that improve both your coding style and enhance the function, please accept them. However, this should not be the accepted answer. The short form is worse that @MosesKoledoye 's version: `[data]*times` and the use of the mutable method `.append()` without returning inside the recursion (it does return but doesn't get used, so its like virtually not returning) is hard to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Because your redefining result2 everytime. Keep result2 outside the function and it should work.

Also you could consider doing data*times to replicate if data is a list or simply do

```
(result2.append(data))*times
```

Comment: Because the list will repeat itself. For example [1,2]*2 = [1,2,1,2]

Answer (score 0):

In the recursion, each time replicate_recur is called, a fresh result2 in new name space is created.

```
[data] * times
```

Would do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: that would multiply my data instead of repeating it

Comment: Did you see square brackets around data?  I am multiplying a list which contains your data, which is equivalent to repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses 'Pass-by-Object-reference', which is why either of the below code should do the trick in your case.

```
def replicate_recur(times, data, result2 = []):
    if times == 1:
        result2.append(data)
    else:
        result2.append(data)
        replicate_recur(times - 1, data)
    return result2
```

When called:

```
>>> replicate_recur(4, 2)
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Alternatively, you could create the result2 list and pass it as an argument to the function. The argument is 'Passed by Object reference', so the same result object is being modified inside the function as well.

```
def replicate_recur(times, data):
    if times == 1:
        result2.append(data)
    else:
        result2.append(data)
        replicate_recur(times - 1, data)
    return result2
```

When called:

```
>>> result2 = []
>>> replicate_recur(4, 2)
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Refer to the below link to learn more about Pass by Object Reference.
[Python:Pass By Object Reference](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)