# Python how to make recursion work with large files

Tags: python, recursion

Hello everyone i'm trying recursion to make reading a json file and appending it a little bit faster. I have a api that gives me a xml file and I convert that file into a json, now i wanna try pushing certain data that is in this json file into a database but because it's a large file I have to go trough it and get the specific data. that's where I wanted recursion to help me with. I have found something on internet that looked like it could help me but the result before and after the recursion where the same, so that's why i'm writing this problem. this is what I tried: [Python recursion in appending lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388155/python-recursion-in-appending-lists) and this is my code so far:

```
@classmethod
def get_unique_measuring_point_ids(cls, times):
    measuring_point_ids = []

    # Return the list if we need to replicate 0 more times
    if times == 0:
        return measuring_point_ids

    # If we reach here at least we have to replicate once
    for event in cls.ndw_events:
        measuring_point_ids.append(event["measuring_point_id"]["uuid"])
    unique_measuring_point_ids = list(unique_everseen(measuring_point_ids))

    # Recursive call to replicate more times, if needed and return the result
    cls.get_unique_measuring_point_ids(times - 1)
    return unique_measuring_point_ids

    this is how i did it before recursion
    # for event in cls.ndw_events:
    #     measuring_point_ids.append(event["measuring_point_id"]["uuid"])
    # unique_measuring_point_ids = list(unique_everseen(measuring_point_ids))
    # return unique_measuring_point_ids
```

Comment: This really doesn't look like a job for recursion. It could be a job for a loop, but if I'm reading this right, it looks like sequence multiplication would do fine: `unique_measuring_point_ids *= times`.

Comment: @user2357112 I looked into using threads aswell but I couldn't figure that out at all. Where would i need to place the `unique_measuring_point_ids *= times` in my code?

Comment: @user2357112 do you know any other way to make reading and appending function go quicker? because it takes 100 second to do this atm and that's without pushing it into a DB